# Getting discounted price for amount of items from user input

Tags: python

I just completed my pre-course assessment.

The project was:

> A cupcake costs 6.50. If you purchase more than 6 cupcakes, each of them will cost 5.50 instead, and if you purchase more than 12, each of them will cost 5.00 instead.
>
> Write a program that asks the user how many cupcakes they want to purchase, and display the total amount they have to pay.

My inputs have been:

```
amt=input("How many cupcakes would you like to but? ")
if amt>=6:
  disc = amt*0.12
elif amt>=12:
  disc=amt*0.24
print(disc)
```

I can't seem to get the code running. Can anyone please dump it down for me?

Comment: Not sure why the 0.12 and 0.24, but even with `int` input, the result will be incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE COMPLETE SOLUTION TO YOUR PROBLEM IS:**

```
amt=int(input("How many cupcakes would you like to but? "))

if amt <= 6:
    pancake_price_650 = 6.50
    price_inferior_6 = amt * pancake_price_650
    print(price_inferior_6)
    
elif amt > 6:   
    pancake_price_550 = 5.50
    price_superior_6 = amt * pancake_price_550
    print(price_superior_6)
    
elif amt > 12:
    pancake_price_500 = 5.00
    price_superior_12 = amt * pancake_price_500
    print(price_superior_12)
```

You were wrong in constructing the logic of conditions.

Also, you haven't converted the input to a string. Input is always read as a string, in your code you haven't read it as an integer. Convert string input to int using `int()`, because `int()` transforms a string into an integer. You need to add `int` before `input`, but put it in parentheses.

Comment: Thank you very much Johan. I know what the problem is now. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Python takes input in `string` format, you need to cast the input into `int` but in your code, you're comparing a `string` with `int` in the conditionals.

```
amt=int(input("How many cupcakes would you like to but? "))
  if amt>=6:
    disc = amt*0.12
  elif amt>=12:
    disc=amt*0.24
print(disc)
```

Comment: Hi buddy! Appreciate your comment.


Correct me if I'm wrong - I basically have to convert my input into an integer before the code will work is that it?

Also, in terms of syntax, is there anything wrong with my subsequent lines?

Comment: As I said above, python takes input in string format. Now, you've taken input as a string which is *amt* and then you're comparing it with 6 which is an int, there's a type mismatch.
Read the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) for input().

Comment: Thank you for the resource. Really appreciate your input.